# ¿Cómo generar los valores de un api según la fecha?

Tags: javascript, html5

¡Hola! mi profesor me dio un API(url) para que listara los gastos(item.amount) según la fecha que sea seleccionada. En el código (.js) que desarrolle cree un scroll para listar las fechas. El problema es que no sé como listar los gastos de la fecha que sea seleccionada. Este es el codigo (.jS) que hice para scroll:

```
function createNode(element) {
return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, el) {
return parent.appendChild(el);
}

const fecha = document.getElementById('list');
const url = 'http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses';

fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
let expenses = data.expenses;
return expenses.map(function(item) {

function loadMore() {
let = option = createNode('option'),
      spanDate = createNode('span');

spanDate.innerHTML = `${item.date}`;

append(option, spanDate);
append(fecha, option);
}

fecha.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
if (fecha.scrollTop) {
loadMore();
}
});

loadMore();

});
});
```

Y este es el codigo html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">   
<h1>Gastos</h1>
<select id="list" class="custom-select">
<option>Fecha</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te he hecho un ejemplo desde cero, que se trata de lo siguiente.

1. Recoger los datos de la api
2. Mostrar las fechas disponible(info que viene desde la api también)
3. Filtrar los datos y mostrar un resumen de  los "productos" y los gastos.

Así que te dejo el código.

```js
let selectionDate = document.getElementById('selectionDate');

//Vamos a coger todas las fechas desde la api.

let url  = 'https://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses'

let originalData = [];



//Obtener los datos.
fetch(url).then(function(resp){
      return resp.json()
     })
    .then(function(data){
       //Array con las fechas unicas.
       let dates = []
       data.expenses.map(function(item){
         originalData.push(item)
         //Si no hay ninguna fecha que coincida lo añadimos al array.
         if(dates.indexOf(item.date) === -1) {
           dates.push(item.date)
         }
       })
      //Finalmente mostramos los options.
      printOptions(dates)
  })
 

function printOptions(dates){

  dates.map(function(item){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = item;
    option.value = item;
    selectionDate.appendChild(option)
  })
 
}

selectionDate.onchange = function(val){
  let fecha =  selectionDate.options[selectionDate.selectedIndex].text
  getDataByMonth(fecha)
}

//Funcion que filtra los datos por la fecha que el usuario ha seleccionado
function getDataByMonth(fecha) {
  let filtredData = originalData.filter(function(item){
      return item.date === fecha;
    })
  
  
  //Una vez que tengamos los datos filtrados, mostramos un resumen
  showDetails(filtredData)
 
}


function showDetails(data){
  //Donde vamos a mostrar los detalles.
  
  let total=0; 
  let allItems = ""
  data.map(function(item){
    allItems += `<li>${item.amount} - ${item.concept}</li>`
    total+= parseInt(item.amount)
  })
  
  allItems += `<h4>Total: ${total}</h4>`

  //Borramos los datos anteriores y mostramos los nuevos
  document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = ""
    .innerHTML = `${allItems}`
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <select id="selectionDate" onchange="onSelectItem(this)">
    <option></option>
      
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <div id="details" >
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que hubiera estado bien es tener 2 registros con la misma fecha, para ver que realmente saca mas de uno registro por esa fecha, pero eso son cosas a mejorar.

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Claro que me ayudaste, gracias por tomarte le tiempo y explicar el código.

Comment: Hola! necesito que ayudes en algo sino es mucha molestia. El profesor me dice que esta bien pero la solución es que la consulta la estas haciendo sobre los datos del JSON y debo hacerlo sobre la URL, debo modificar la URL para sacar los datos. El me dio este ejemplo : http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/expenses   cada vez que escojo una fecha para genere los valores la URL cambia.

Comment: Para poder hacer eso, necesitas conocer los parámetros que se le tiene que pasar a la url. Has intentado hacer algo?

Comment: Solo me dio como pista el ejemplo (la URL) que te mostré, que viera como se modifica cada vez que escogía una fecha. Según solo es cambiar la URL, la URL es un STRING.  Y si tenia dudas mirara  en network de Chrome

Comment: Entiendo, pero te explico, para poder filtrar esos datos yo necesito decirle a la url por el parametro que hoy a filtrar, es decir un ejemplo podria ser.
http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/expenses?month=10&year=2018

Con esto le estoy diciendo que me de todo del mes 10 y del año 2018. 

Entonces yo me refiero a eso para poder cambiar el código. Necesito saber los parámetros que recibe la url.

Comment: Ah ok! también le hice esa pregunta y me  respondió que en el network esta esa información pero realmente he mirado no sé en que parte :(  . pdta: gracias por tu paciencia